# Underscorejs Object to Collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, underscore.js

Just exists a underscoreJs method to convert a Object having some properties to an Collection of objects having a key property?

I mean if exists a simple method in *underscorejs* that is equivalent of this:

```
function objectToCollection(obj, propertyKey) {
    return _.map(obj, function(o, key) {
        b[propertyKey] = key;
        return o;
    });
}

var obj = {
    prop1: {val:2},
    prop2: {val:3},
    prop3: {val:5},
    prop4: {val:7}
};

objectToCollection(obj, 'name');
```

Result:

```
[
    {name: 'prop1', val: 2},
    {name: 'prop2', val: 3},
    {name: 'prop3', val: 5},
    {name: 'prop4', val: 7}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys` and `map`

```
var output = Object.keys(obj).map( s => ({...obj[s], name:s}) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var obj = {
    prop1: {val:2},
    prop2: {val:3},
    prop3: {val:5},
    prop4: {val:7}
};
var output = Object.keys(obj).map( s => ({...obj[s], name:s}) );

console.log( output );
```

Comment: I ask if exists a simple method, not a short implementation

Comment: Sure, can you define and elaborate on *simple method* in your question itself?

Comment: if just exist a method inside undescorejs similar to *objectToCollection* function.
the question (look the title) is relative to *underscorejs* not javascript in general

Answer (score 0):

Since `underscore's` map (even all the methods that works on collection) can work directly on `Object`, for this kind of transformation no extra function is needed there.

`_.map(obj)` it will just transform all the values of the object to a collection

Here is an example for your specific case (transformation), where you want to preserve the keys inside each object with a property `name`:

```js
var obj = {
    prop1: {val:2},
    prop2: {val:3},
    prop3: {val:5},
    prop4: {val:7}
}
var array = _.map(obj, (v, name) => ({...v, name}));

console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```